# Why was my answer deleted last night?

Tags: support, specific-answer, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

Why was my answer to this question deleted?

[How do I effectively get people to look past my age when considering my abilities, if they know how old I am?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/how-do-i-effectively-get-people-to-look-past-my-age-when-considering-my-abilitie)

My answer is below, for reference.  I thought it was a good one - and certainly not delete-worthy:

> I think that the question as written is overly broad; here, context is
>   crucial, and the subject matter of the online community that you
>   moderate is relevant information that you'd need to provide, in order
>   to get a good answer.
>
> However, let's assume that this IPS site is the online community that
>   you moderate; but this means that we can apply the guidelines from the
>   diamond moderator Catija:
>
> [1]
>   [For your consideration: "On Topic" help page contents](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2390/for-your-consideration-on-topic-help-page-contents)
>
> and you may immediately refer the user to those guidelines; in other
>   words, if that user is disputing your abilities to moderate IPS, have
>   him or her contact the Stack Exchange staff members.  There is no need
>   for you to say anything more.
>
> Now in general, e.g. not an IPS community, not necessarily a Stack
>   Exchange site, I would say that the subject matter is crucial.  For
>   instance, it is natural and entirely justifiable for someone looking
>   to ask a question about parenting, on some parenting Q&A forum, to
>   expect that the moderators are *not* teenagers -- unless a teenage
>   moderator has had *relevant experience* in parenting.
>
> So, I think it's important not to conflate maturity with subject
>   matter expertise.
>
> If you have subject matter expertise (say, in parenting), then again,
>   refer the user to that online community's staff members.  You *could*
>   briefly tell the user that you are qualified to moderate and give your
>   reasons, but that's not really necessary.
>
> If for some reason you are moderating an online community that doesn't
>   have staff members that can help, then I'd recommend showing that you
>   are qualified to moderate through your actions, e.g. with high quality
>   answer posts, helpful comments, good conflict management, etc., rather
>   than verbalizing it.

Comment: I can't speak to why it was deleted, but if you think a question is too broad then you shouldn't be posting an answer. You should be working to edit the question to reduce it's scope, or working to get it closed by flagging or voting.

Comment: Another gratuitous deletion. If they don't like your answer people can downvote. I don't see why your answer needed to be deleted. I have voted to undelete.

Comment: @EnglishStudent The question has nothing to do with subject matter expertise and that's all the answer discusses. As written, this doesn't actually answer the question "How do I communicate to someone that my age doesn't affect my ability to moderate". The question is specifically asking how to **tell them** when they ask but the answer is focused entirely on not needing to answer the question - that doesn't really provide a solution to Arwen's question.

Comment: That makes it much clearer why they deleted that answer. Thanks for explaining (in a detailed answer here) how it doesn't answer the question @Catija. How do I retract my undelete vote?

Comment: @EnglishStudent Delete/Undelete votes stick; there's no taking them back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer fails the most important test:

### Answers must [answer the question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/can-answers-be-off-topic-how-to-deal-with-answers-that-address-legal-issues/1385#1385)

What's the question:

> Title: **How do I effectively get people to look past my age when considering my abilities, if they know how old I am?**
> How do I get them to trust my abilities despite my age?

Your answer is:

> I'd recommend showing that you are qualified to moderate through your actions, e.g. with high quality answer posts, helpful comments, good conflict management, etc., rather than verbalizing it.

But the OP already says that's part of what they're doing:

> So, while I hope that my actions will speak for themselves, I'm also looking for a way to communicate my response to this.

This wasn't posted in the question until recently but a (now) deleted comment said it an hour before your answer was posted. We generally hope that people will include additional info in the question but it's really valuable for you to read comments before answering:

[image: Deleted comment from 10 hours ago]

To use absolute time, that's 2018-01-23 10:20:56Z. Your answer was posted at 2018-01-23 11:21:43Z - an hour later.

So, your answer isn't what the question is looking for - a way to directly communicate to someone about moderation.

Your answer is 90% "this is why people don't trust you - because at your age, you can't be an expert in this topic", 5% "your question isn't clear", and 5% "Answer that you already know".

To address that first 5%, what sphennings wrote in a comment is absolutely true.

> I can't speak to why it was deleted, but if you think a question is too broad then you shouldn't be posting an answer. You should be working to edit the question to reduce it's scope, or working to get it closed by flagging or voting. – sphennings 1 hour ago

The first paragraph of your answer clearly indicates that you think the question isn't ready to be answered... so **don't** answer it.

#### How to fix your answer:

If you want to actually address the OP's question, consider the sites they **actually** moderate rather than sites they *obviously* don't. Arwen is neither an IPS mod nor a Parenting mod. They're a moderator on Literature, which is entirely different. In chat you seemed to be a bit concerned about life experience... but "experience" on Literature is reading books... something that I know Arwen does quite a bit. Heck, even their username is book-related.

Consider the actual question - focus your answer on how Arwen can communicate with the user directly - without appealing to staff or ignoring the question or hoping that their contributions to the site are enough - if they were enough, the user wouldn't have asked the question in the first place!

If you edit your answer to address these concerns, I'm sure that it can be undeleted but, until then, it will stay deleted.

Comment: Asking for context and assuming it **is not** an acceptable way to answer a question. The first is what comments are for. And, no, I don't assume that you know that... though if you don't, I'd be surprised. The last two paragraphs are a suggestion for how to edit your answer to make it worthy of undeletion, not commentary on why it was deleted.

Comment: @D.Hutchinson answering "how do I communicate with X" with "tell X he can escalate his complaint" misses the point.  The OP is trying to have the sort of conversation that *averts the need* for anybody to escalate anything.  Your answer doesn't answer the question.  Further, you started out by essentially saying it should be closed, so it's peculiar that you answered instead of voting to close.

Comment: "So, while I hope that my actions will speak for themselves, I'm also looking for a way to communicate my response to this." - He's directly asking how to communicate - telling him to go to staff or whatever for help undermines his goal of wanting to do the communication himself, so it's not really answering what he's expressly asked for. (As many others have pointed out).

Comment: Ok, drop it @D.Hutchinson. Catija went far out of her way to answer your support question here; the critical issue with your answer was described in the first two sentences: **it didn't answer the question.** Are there other answers that have this issue? Probably; it's a super-common issue that's been discussed here repeatedly, and there are still many pending flags on the thread which *probably could've been handled* if mods weren't wasting time on this discussion. Doesn't matter; your answer was deleted for the usual reason. You have all the information you need; use it or don't.