# Why did my answer get deleted?

Tags: support, faq

I've answered a question, but my answer was later deleted--it even had some upvotes! Why did this happen? What can I do?

Comment: This would do well with a matching "My answer was deleted...now what?" FAQ post. I'm not going to have time today to write it, so if anyone wants to, it's up for grabs :)

Comment: @BlackThorn [the relevant help page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) is a general SE page that leaves off with "The community-curated FAQ contains more details." This question is tagged [meta-tag:faq-proposed] to hopefully be part of that FAQ. See [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3177/11811) for more.

Comment: yup, I gotta be sure to read the tags more frequently. I don't have a problem with this then.

Comment: @BlackThorn no worries! :) if you think this is too broad for the FAQ or still not a good fit, feel free to dv/VTC

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Official guidance from Stack Exchange can be found in [the help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).*

We're happy that you've taken the time to write an answer, but we hold our answers to a very high standard here. Your answer may have been deleted because...

- It was a ["Do this" answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2003/11811) with [little or no explanation](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3584/11659) for why you think this answer is the correct course of action.
- It doesn't answer the question that was asked. This may be one of the following two cases:

  - You're trying to write a frame challenge, but haven't fulfilled all the requirements. See the [frame challenge FAQ](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511/11811) for more.
  - You're [explaining the situation instead of giving a solution](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2413/11811) or you're giving a solution to a different problem than the one asked.
- It [does not involve any interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471/11811) and thus is not a fit for this site.
- It suggests the same solution as another answer that was posted earlier.
- It violates the ["Be Nice"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Please check the comments on your answer for more details on why it may have been deleted.

Do not repost deleted answers. Instead, it is possible for answers to be undeleted if they are improved.

- First, edit your answer to address the issues that caused its deletion, making sure to follow the guidelines at [How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer).
- If your answer was deleted by the community, users with sufficient privileges can vote to undelete.
- If your answer was deleted by a moderator, only a moderator can undelete it. You'll need to flag your answer, select "in need of moderator intervention", and explain that you've improved it. The moderators can then review your answer for undeletion.