# Why was my Answer wrongly deleted? Yes, this again

Tags: discussion

[(How) can I ask gifts be in cash/check instead of more restrictive instruments?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20707/how-can-i-ask-gifts-be-in-cash-check-instead-of-more-restrictive-instruments/20716#20716)

It answers the headline question directly and succinctly.  There is no reason for anything other than Politeness when asking this to friends and family.

Also, I'm the only one to address the equally important secondary question:

**Is it possible to make it easier on myself without taking away whatever pleasure the givers find in giving me plastic rectangles?**

I'll even open it up to explain how the other remain answers are any better.  For example, they both mention a savings account or something which OP doesn't even hint at.

I am open to any evidence based claims from the Question or my Answer.

Comment: A comment left under your answer was "While it's helpful to identify which skills are needed, can you provide some advice on actually putting that into practice? How can OP politely communicate their preferences? For instance, knowing when to bring it up and when/if to let it go would be useful." The comment is good advice; your answer doesn't really address the specifics of how politeness should be used here.

Comment: @HDE226868 I saw the comment, but it's not relevant for the reasons above.  I don't expect them to actually justify the deletion, they've never been able to in the past.  It's clearly personal.  If you look at WendyG's Answer, EmC made an essentially identical comment which WendyG flatly refused to address and that Answer has not been deleted.

Comment: You *haven't* given any rationale above, Johns, and you haven't given any reasons why the comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @HDE226868 "There is no reason for anything other than Politeness when asking this to friends and family."  Sorry, I did.  If the Answer required and example, I would have given one, as I often do. This case did not warrant it.

Comment: @Johns-305 Please don't comment on other users' answers to complain. The other answer is not deleted because the community hasn't voted to delete it. Notice that I wasn't the one who deleted your answer; it was three different reviewers.

Comment: @Johns-305 That's about as vague as answering a question on Stack Overflow by saying "You need to delete some of your code" and not going into any more details. Just saying "Politeness" doesn't help anyone. Also, as EmC said, the community voted to deleted your answer, and the other answers you're mentioning have positive scores, so a mod would be needed to step in and delete it unilaterally.

Comment: @EmC It's not a complaint.  I'm asking for an explanation for the inconsistent treatment.  I was hoping they would have learned from our last incident, but I guess I'm still be treated unfairly for reasons unrelated to my participation (#6 for the quarter).

Comment: @HDE226868 Except "You shouldn't be doing that at all" is perfectly reasonable answer to many questions on SE.  In fact, I just use it earlier today.  No reason to add unnecessary complication.

Comment: Hey Johns, thanks for using a non-demanding title this time. I'm sorry your answer was deleted, but as far as your concerns about inconsistency--it appears your answer was deleted from 3 delete votes from high-rep users. The other answer you're comparing yours to, however, does not have a negative score, which means it'll take more than 3 votes to delete it. Perhaps yours was deleted before theirs because it takes longer to get >3 votes to delete?

Comment: @scohe001 My Answer is from roughly the same timeframe as the others yet my was delete >12 hours ago, meaning, they've had twice as much time to garner upvotes.  Also, I had a +14 Answer Deleted so clearly Mods don't consider the Community opinion.  Fun Fact, the Accepted Answer there was only +12.

Comment: Just a reminder that upvotes have no bearing on whether something is on topic or meets the minimum requirements of a good IPS answer. Upvotes only mean that someone found something amusing or useful. Many users came to this site because of posts featured in the Hot Network Question sidebar. If they have the association bonus they will start with 101 rep, which is enough to upvote posts. Their first and only action on the site could be upvoting a post that they like. Most of these users have no interest in participating in community moderation, or an awareness of a particular site's policies.

Comment: If upvotes were the only metric that mattered there wouldn't be a need for review queues, or flagging.

Comment: @sphennings Upvotes are unrelated to flagging or moderation queues.  I know how the site works.  Also, IPS no longer appears in HNQ so...yeah....  There's also that equal treatment thing where my Answer is Deleted while another Answer with the exact same 'problem' is not.  So...yeah...

Comment: @Johns-305 Your deleted answer with 14 net upvotes was before we became unlisted from HNQ. While it hasn't been deleted, action has been taken about the answer you referenced. Similar comments have been made pointing out the answer's issues. It has entered the LQP queue and has received multiple votes to delete it. However with its positive score it won't be deleted automatically. Instead it will be recommended to moderators for deletion once it has received sufficient votes.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry, I don't follow.  The +14 Answer is Deleted.

Comment: @Johns-305 I should have clarified. With the exception of the first sentence I was talking about the other answer that is currently in the LQP review queue for the "Ask for gifts in cash" question.

Comment: @sphennings Still don't understand.  That Answer appears as Deleted as well...that's why were talking about it.  Also, it has no Upvotes because it quashed too quickly for the community to express an opinion.  There are two undelete votes.

Comment: You're complaining about unequal treatment. Other answers to that question are going through the same process that yours went through. Yours just garnered a few more downvotes earlier in the process. This isn't unequal treatment this is the site working as intended.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry, but no, it didn't.  It has 1 downvote and was Deleted at just ~12 hours.  WendyG's answer has now 3 downvotes and remains for >2 days now.  Noon's Answer has 1 downvote, same as mine, and is approaching the 12 hour mark.  I am waiting to see both Deleted very soon.  Otherwise, yes, unequal treatment.  That's what the evidence indicates.

Comment: I'm starting to think we could probably make a branch of our FAQ on why answers get deleted solely out of this guys meta posts.

Comment: @JessK Well, we do have a proposed FAQ [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/why-did-my-answer-get-deleted) ;) maybe we ought to add a point about how upvotes and other currently visible answers are largely irrelevant?

Answer (score 7):

Background #1: I'm one of the 3 who voted to delete this answer. I'm not a serial downvoter at all, and I'd rather use positive and nice ways to achieve things than anything else, anytime it's possible. Even if, sometimes, " *'NO' is a complete sentence.* "

Background #2: to me, InterPersonal Skills are very often based upon and driven by feelings, and the way to (re)act when facing a situation you have no response to. You interact with people, most of the time, walking on eggs and with a real need of sugar-coating.

IMO, you **can't** see/use/recommend anything on IPS and say: "*use it like a switch, it's ON/OFF. Period.*" No need to explain why it works, or the risks you face if you misuse it?

Coming to that analogy, I'll use the electrical switch as an image.

- ON: light.
- OFF: no light.

But no explanation about the "*how it works*", or "*why you should be careful*", or "*this is the light side / beware of the dark side*", "*risk of shorting*", and so on...

Is that what we want on IPS? Just a plain "put the switch ON/OFF"? I'd say no. Please, no.

And that's what I feel when reading some of your answers. This "raw" feeling of the switch. I'll quote you:

> Except "You shouldn't be doing that at all" is perfectly reasonable answer to many questions on SE. In fact, I just use it earlier today. No reason to add unnecessary complication.

- to many questions on SE? **yes**. When it requires a Yes/NO answer. A work/doesn't work answer. When you're facing a **technical** problem. But not at all, IMO, when dealing with real people, with real feelings, with real problems...
- In fact, I just use it earlier today. -> the one I think about is [this one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20725/tactifully-telling-my-cousin-that-she-might-do-too-much-chores). To me, it's a "*straight to the point answer with no explanation and without a true knowledge of the French culture*". Still, it gets some UV and is top-rated. But, if you want to offer a frame-challenge and/or explain why a POV from different culture can be helful, then, explaining **is much more than important**.
- No reason to add unnecessary complication -> IPS **are** about reasons and complications, because human being **IS** complicated, his feelings, his nature. Mankind and its problems aren't a ON/OFF switch.

---

As a kind of conclusion, even if Donald Trump is POTUS, he's not the representative image of ALL American Citizens. And [Pepe Le Pew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pep%C3%A9_Le_Pew) isn't the one of all French :D

I'm not trying to be controversial or trying to oppose them, I was just being stereotypical, and picking one character in each culture. Like a ON/OFF, 2 extreme of the scale. But I'd rather think (and, for the sake of Mankind, **believe**) that we have a **very** large choice on the spectrum between those 2 ;)

Can we be straight to the point? Yes.

Do we owe people explanation and clarification? Yes.

Sometimes, you can "*straddle the fence*" ("*menager la chèvre et le chou*" would say the French), even if, sometimes, you can't. The "**how's**" and "**why's**" are important.

Comment: Some people might find a direct, to-the-point Answer useful.  I'm very saddened that diversity in Answers is not accepted here.  I really don't understand such intolerance of opinion.  When can I expect my **perfectly legitimate Answer** to be restored?

Comment: *Some people might find a direct, to-the-point Answer useful* -> and it is!... **but** without any explanation, it sounds like a *try this* answer, who cares, really... and that's not what is expected here, the community decided so, here on meta, and on the main site.

Comment: Look, I hate to rehash this again, but it would help if you actually read the Answers before commenting.  I did not give a 'try this' Answer.  The Question was "How can I ask.."  My Answer is essentially, Politely.  That all OP needs to do.  Notice, SZCZERZO KŁY opens with "Have you tried..." so if "try this" Answers are unacceptable, please have that one Deleted immediately as well.

Comment: @Johns-305 If your answer was **perfectly legitimate**, the community wouldn't have made a collective vote to delete it.  You have more "why is my answer deleted" posts on meta than any other single user because you ignore the explanations given to you and expect the results to change.  You've provided other great answers in the past that *have* met answer requirements... Please listen to the input being given to you to improve your answer instead of bickering with the people trying to help you.

Comment: @JessK. Sorry, this is not a 'community' vote.  It's 3 people voting explicitly *against* the community.  As noted above, this has happened before on an Answer with a higher Community score (upvote) than even the Accepted Answer.  I'm perfectly happy to let the real Community judge but I have a big problem when 3 users can delete a perfectly legitimate Answer with no justification at all.

Comment: @Johns-305 You need 3 people if the answer has a negative score. You need 6 (plus a mod) if the answer has a positive one.

Comment: @Noon "your answer was deleted from 3 delete votes from high-rep users" -  scohe001.

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes, it was. But this was only possible because your answer had a negative score, it would have require six user + a mod otherwise

Comment: @Noon A score of -1.  That tells me a lot.  Very sad the delete voters a blocking an otherwise perfectly legitimate answer to both OP's questions.  Note, no one else has addressed the second issue.  :(  I'm done.

Comment: I like the analogy you used. Situations are often more complicated than they seem, and short, simple answers often (usually?) miss most of the important nuances of the issue, and therefore don't really help anyone.

Comment: @Johns-305 You can effectively count it as 4 then because I would agree your answer is insufficient and lacks an explanation as to how to use the skill.  It doesn't matter how succinct the answer **could** be, the point of the matter is that we have guidelines in place that require answers to be explanatory **for those who lack interpersonal skills/reasoning and cannot fill in the blanks on their own**.  Your answer does not meet that requirement, so it's deleted and won't be restored unless you update it according to the explanations being very graciously given to you in the answer above.

Comment: @JessK. Then why is WendyG's Answer not Deleted?  Em C (a full Moderator no less) asked for the exact same clarification and WendyG flatly refused.  In this case, it's either both or neither.  I'm being treated very unfairly.

Comment: @Johns-305 WendyG's answer is in the review queue. Moderators generally wait for the community to complete the review task before taking further action (if any is even needed at that point).

Comment: @EmC In the queue for >2 Days while mine was Deleted in ~12 hours.  I get it.

Comment: @Johns-305 You can continue to create a false sense of fear/anger that the community is specifically out to get **you**, or you can read into the detailed answers that continue to be provided to you by very *patient* members on how you can improve your answers to get them restored.  The answers that are provided to you are always upvoted, while your original questions on meta continue to be downvoted... a good sign that the advice being given to you is agreed upon by the community and the "you're all out to get me" attitude is not true or favorable...  People keep trying to help you, let them.

Comment: @JessK. I am able to provide voluminous evidence to justify my case.  The detractors are not.  It's that simple.  Here's the thing, I don't need help and my Answers don't need improving (unless there is a factual or contextual defect). **They are how I choose to answer a question**.  Deleting answers with no reason (other than opinion) is not helpful to anyone.  If an Answer so bad, **let the community downvote it**.  That's how SE is supposed to work.  Moderators and high rep uses wielding their power to enforce their *opinion* in the community is contrary to that ethos.

Comment: @Johns-305 Moderators aren't the ones even deleting your answers.  It's clear you're just out to argue, not to actually improve your answers or learn how to write an answer that fits the guideline **requirements** for this stack.  I wish I could help you, as it seems very stressful to constantly feel the victim of planned attacks, but the only one able to help you past that mindset is yourself.  I've seen great answers from you before, and believe you could be a great contributor here if you followed the guidelines and didn't feel your answers were above following them.  Good luck, John!

Comment: @JessK. "Moderators and *high rep use[r]s* " <- example of actual evidence.  Thanks for acknowledging my contributions!  And my current rep indicates consistently valuable Answers.  Meaning, it's the mods and high rep users that are the outliers and acting against the interest of the community.  My mindset is fine as this is the only forum where this is a problem.  Also indicating the problem isn't with me. Sorry, that how evidence works.  I'm willing to let this go.  If they don't like an Answer, just downvote with a comment.  That's how it works everywhere else.

Comment: @Johns-305 IPS isn't "everywhere else". Yes, IPS works differently from other stacks. There are some reasons for that, one of them being that we needed and still need very strict rules to make this site a success. I know those rules may seem complicated, pointless and hard to follow. But they all have a point and, if you are unable or unwilling to follow them, maybe it's best that you stop contributing altogether

Comment: @Noon The rules shouldn't be complicated and hard to follow.  Also, I'd be more willing to 'follow' them if they were applied consistently.  For example, your Answer on this question now has -1 score.  Should I expect it to be Deleted within the hour?  Honestly, this is what bothers me most.  The reasons given for this deletion apply to WendyG and your Answer, yet they remain.  Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: @Johns-305 I don't understand, why do you think my answer should be deleted/doesn't follow the guidelines?

Comment: @Noon I'm simply attempting to apply the same standard to your Answer as mine.  Mine was deleted in ~12 hrs with -1 score.  Your Answer also had -1 Score and was incomplete regarding OP's original questions.  That's why I say I'm being treated unequally.

Comment: @Johns-305 I still don't understand, why do you think my answer is incomplete? What did I miss?

Comment: @Noon There are two distinct questions: **(How) can I ask...?** and **Is it possible to make it easier on myself...?**  Admittedly, the second one is not an Interpersonal Skill unless you count it as Personal Accommodation (ie. not imposing on someone).  OP asked nonetheless and there is a solution relatable directly to OP's own comments.  Your Answer is fine, but to Delete mine for, apparently, not providing an example of a Polite Question is raises the bar for all Answers.

Comment: @Noon Besides, do we really think Askers are so narrowly focused they would process only 1 Answer?  No, they'll probably read most/all and draw a combined conclusion.

Comment: @Johns-305 I was under the impression that both questions were, mostly, the same and that I was answering both. But anyway, this is off-topic and we should stop talking about that here.

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum**

I think it's important to give this discussion a second (third?) try, so there I go. I didn't want to edit my first answer, as this is just a offshoot that has its own developpment, and root question/problem. Not only I wish this could be helpful, but it may question / help / "*protect*" our (still weak and recovering) IPS community, its goals and tools.

I'm not (or consider myself) an Avenger ^^, but since I was kind of first-on-line on this one, I'll keep it running. I'm not calling names, just trying to answer you again, John, and clarify some points. But you'll be the example I'll choose, because you initiated this discussion that, IMO, is far more wide and broad than a single answer (yours, or mine). It's about what the Community has decided as time went by, and all of the developments this stack has had...

What I'm thinking of right now is [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20749/how-to-decline-food-without-sounding-picky). You stand your ground. I'll not DV or flag or even review this answer. This is **not** the point, and **no**, I don't think you're targeted. So, here are my thoughts about that, and I'll give my analyze and POV.

This is (IMO) another "*switch-answer*", and we should avoid that. Why?

> "*I would expect Parents to be familiar with such restrictions*" -> we don't know. So, it looks like "counting chickens before they are hatched".

**It lacks background and clarification from OP** -> assessing this and answering is like "shooting in the dark". You may hit the target, or not :)

> "*The first Interpersonal Skill to use is simple Honesty*" -> but please, tell a white lie.

Randomly add some spice in the dish, and see if it suits your taste and your parents. Later, OP added this comment: "But because the reactions aren't anaphylactic shock, there's a whole discussion on whether its pickiness or actual allergies".

> "*The next Interpersonal Skill is Personal Accommodation*" -> is this a skill?!

To me, it's a life-hack. More important, why would OP use this? What are the pros and cons? The possible outcome? I don't say that it's a bad idea, just that it would really benefit of some explanation and, if possible, be experienced/knowledge based.

> "*you can use the Interpersonal Skill of Flattery*" -> this, I can't agree.

Worst advice possible, the one that can badly backfire...  Flattery is often associated with hypocrisy, and toadyism, and people usually hate this.

> "*Finally, have a plan in case [...] but you should be prepared*" -> switch ON/OFF, try this, and if it doesn't work, plan B.

My understanding and conclusion are that, no matter if it has UV, this is **not** following the rules IPS has set. And, before anything else, rules can be discussed, here, on meta, rather than writing answers that won't fit. You're right to ask for a change, but while it's discussed/agreed here, **we** (not *you* only) should refrain from many things like the two main ones following:

- accepting questions that don't fit the pre-defined model (but ask for clarification / edits...)
- answering (FGITW syndrom) those questions.

If I had to say something that would reach a personal level for **any of us**, I'd point that we all can be, as individual, another valuable contributor if we follow the play-book the coach has set, and play with the team. Not for our own sake, not to attract the spotlight, not for being the bigshot. For the team. You don't win a battle/war/revolution by beating your opponent or losing our lives, but by protecting/saving the life of the ones you love. Sacrificing our [ pride / life / internet points / you name it ] at the benefit of the group is the heart of the problem, the crux of our involvement to help others.

If **we** are wrong, let's hold our hands and die as a **team**.

---

If you folks think this is unclear, too broad or off-topic, or if I'm wrong with this, or if it should be part of another discussion, or just deleted, please comment, let me/us know. Thanks.

Comment: I know this may come across as ungrateful, but I have to point out you are simply incorrect on all points.  A 'sensitivity' as OP describe it likely a mild allergy, hence, not a lie.  Personal Accommodation is a situational Interpersonal Skill to avoid the interpersonal action of imposition.  BTW, do you really think OP wouldn't understand the point of brining extra food was so Spouse could eat it?  I guess I have a little more faith in people.  Your opinion on Flattery is just, well, very sad.  How about you write a compliant Answer?  Be sure to follow all the 'rules' so I have an example.

Comment: Also, the first part is specifically meant to inform OP that they are not alone in this situation, and they are not facing unique interpersonal crisis with Parents.  This is a very common tactic.  I'm surprised you didn't pick up on that.

Comment: @Johns-305 : I can't and won't answer because I have **no** good idea that could help or would work, or known/personal experience that can succeed, no data, no explanation, nothing that could back-up any assessement I would tell/advice OP... nothing. For the same reason, I looked for some Q/A we have in stock (about vegan or even my mom cooking too much food for us ^^) and found nothing helpful. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 - I know what won't work (in some cases) because I have **exactly** the same problem with GF (who doesn't like meat, can eat it, but doesn't enjoy) and Mother who is straight in her boots and will not listen, and still cook too much, and cook meat. No trick ever worked yet. What can I tell OP? here are all the things we tried and that failed?...

Comment: Umm....bring more food.  It's right there in my Answer.  I never even hinted Mother would or should change her cooking.  Bring Spouse food and compliment Mother so she doesn't feel rejected.  How is this not clear?  No point in continuing this.  Thanks.

Comment: "*I'm surprised you didn't pick up on that*" -> sorry, I missed it. Really, no kidding. I didn't get the point. And that's why, quoting @Jess-K ("*we have guidelines in place that require answers to be explanatory for those who lack interpersonal skills/reasoning and cannot fill in the blanks on their own.*") I'd really love reading answer that can be helpful for everybody :) I'm sure you can make the extra step.

Comment: @Johns-305 : "*this may come across as ungrateful*" -> I don't see it like that :) we discuss, (dis)agree, no big deal... "*but I have to point out you are simply incorrect on all points*" -> only my POV, can be wrong, argued, whatever, no big deal again. What I'm trying, like many users here, is that no one pushes  while some others try to pull the other way around and that all of our efforts end with wasted time and energy ;)

Comment: reading the answer again and again, I just found out something, and I don't know if I'm misunderstanding or misinterpreting. Please anyone correct my english if I'm wrong :) -> *First, this is at all an uncommon situation so you're not alone in facing this with Parents.* = **SO** -> if *the first part is specifically meant to inform OP that they are not alone in this situation*, shouldn't it be *First, this is **NOT** at all an uncommon...*"? And that may be the reason some (including me) didn't properly got it?